# UIPickerView as UITextField Input mode instead of keyboard

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, uipickerview

I would like to use a picker view instead of a keyboard. 
The problem is that I have my pickerView always on my viewController and so I can't use :`textField.inputView = pickerView` as always. 
I tried using the delegate of the UITextField textFieldDidEndEditing and it works but I' don't see real time changing the text of my textField.

Answer (score 0):

Solvd. I used
 `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int` method to display the text in the textField